# How can I stream audio file with chunks in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to stream a wav file in one of my endpoints and I have a code like below:

```py
async def stream_audio(uid: str):
    track = await Song.find_one({"slug": uid})
    os.chdir(config("DLL_AUDIO_FILES"))
    async with aiofiles.open(f"{track.get('file_slug')}.wav", mode="rb") as f:
        buff = io.BytesIO(await f.read())
        buff.seek(0)
        return StreamingResponse(buff, media_type="audio/aac")
```

but whenever I try this endpoint I get something like this in response:

```
ÿ  ÿÿ ÿÿþÿþÿüÿþÿýÿûÿûÿùÿûÿöÿúÿ÷ÿþÿöÿúÿüÿôÿøÿýÿöÿøÿÿÿ÷ÿøÿÿÿùÿöÿþÿýÿöÿÿÿþÿþÿúÿþÿþÿüÿþÿýÿûÿûÿúÿúÿýÿþÿ ýÿ ûÿûÿÿÿ
```

I want to know how can I stream my audio file in chunks and what is the correct way?
thanks.

Comment: That seems to be binary data - which is what you're returning. Also, reading a `.wav` file and returning it as having `aac` as it's defined type will be _very_ confusing for your clients, as you're giving them raw wav data, but are saying that it's `audio/aac` data. Setting a different `media_type` will _not actually convert the data_, it just tells the client _what the data is already encoded as_. How you use what you're returning from the endpoint (compare the returned data with what the source data is) depends on what you want it's for - download/streaming/live/etc.